# DropDownListFor selected value does not work with property in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, get, selecteditem, html.dropdownlistfor

I have problems to set the default selected value of a DropDownList with DropDownListFor in ASP MVC 4.

When the property which I want to preselect is in a list it's never selected by default as expected.

Here is my code reduced to the important stuff:

Models:

```
public class Renter
{
    ...
    public virtual List<RentLine> RentLines { get; set; }
    ...

    public Renter()
    {
        ...
        RentLines = new List<RentLine>();
        ...
    }
}

public class RentLine
{
    ...
    public Guid RenterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Renter Renter { get; set; }  
    public Guid GarageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Garage Garage { get; set; }
    ...

    public RentLine()
    {
        //
        // Testcase for default value in dropdownlist
        //
        GarageId = new Guid("e926dcac-05ac-4fc1-92a2-014345e6e11c");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Hinzufuegen()
{
    var model = new AddRenterViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddRenterViewModel
{
    public Renter Renter { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> RentableGarageItems { get; set; }

    ...

    public AddRenterViewModel()
    {
        Renter = new Renter();
        Renter.RentLines.Add(new RentLine());

        RentableGarageItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var garage in Singleton.Instance.Entities.GetRentableGarages().OrderBy(g => g.No))
        {
            RentableGarageItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text = garage.No.ToString(), Value = garage.Id.ToString()});
        }
    }   
}
```

View:

```
@model Grossgaragenverwaltung.ViewModels.AddRenterViewModel
...
Garage Nr. @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId, Model.RentableGarageItems) @* No selected value *@
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId) @* Shows the id 'e926dcac-05ac-4fc1-92a2-014345e6e11c' as set in the constructor *@
...
```

Here is the result, no selected value:

```
Garage Nr.
<select id="Renter_RentLines_0__GarageId" name="Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId" data-val-required="Das Feld "GarageId" ist erforderlich." data-val="true">
<option value="225a761d-7d12-4e02-9d72-d54fb6934f05">1</option>
<option value="d28fb4fb-d65b-4674-90d6-a4ab9636be80">2</option>
<option value="e06b520b-e876-4870-b321-dc65f77967a7">3</option>
<option value="56832d98-aa5a-4e1a-af44-2d7e00f2bb3a">4</option>
<option value="551f1fa9-13a5-40ce-b795-50063e605027">5</option>
<option value="bace4b40-92ab-4757-9716-2a2878c2c9e8">6</option>
<option value="f9baf45b-96bf-463e-a234-a1522bfc9b9b">7</option>
<option value="91d1d866-6346-4ab0-b2aa-35b56eeaf2b0">8</option>
<option value="62eb3727-eab2-4180-90cd-7dc59119f44e">9</option>
<option value="59768097-c772-4421-b907-a24397a106f5">10</option>
<option value="270acf6b-e4e3-41c3-86dd-4381a313848a">11</option>
<option value="923269cd-1ead-4346-90ce-6344acda5b1b">12</option>
<option value="981ee61e-408b-4b08-a7d3-26c909f04a9d">13</option>
<option value="f1c5043c-fe41-4a8e-8c58-e88363885de4">14</option>
<option value="e926dcac-05ac-4fc1-92a2-014345e6e11c">15</option>
<option value="5577dc00-7cfa-4bcd-99ad-3f356e4325ae">16</option>
</select>
<input id="Renter_RentLines_0__GarageId" type="text" value="e926dcac-05ac-4fc1-92a2-014345e6e11c" name="Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId">
```

How can i get this work?

UPDATE:
Here is a working example where everything works like expected, the problem occurs only in the case you see above:

```
public class Renter
{
    ...
    public Salutation Salutation { get; set; }
    ...

    public Renter()
    {
        ...
        Salutation = Salutation.Male;
        ...
    }
}

public ActionResult Hinzufuegen()
{
    var model = new AddRenterViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

public class AddRenterViewModel
{
    public Renter Renter { get; set; }

    public List&lt;SelectListItem&gt; SalutationItems { get; set; }

    ...

    public AddRenterViewModel()
    {
        Renter = new Renter();
        Renter.RentLines.Add(new RentLine());

        SalutationItems = new List&lt;SelectListItem&gt;();
        foreach (Salutation salutation in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Salutation)))
        {
           SalutationItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = NameEnum.GetName(salutation), Value = salutation.ToString() });
        }
    }   
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m =&gt; m.Renter.Salutation, Model.SalutationItems)

&lt;select id="Renter_Salutation" name="Renter.Salutation" data-val-required="Das Feld "Salutation" ist erforderlich." data-val="true"&gt;
&lt;option value="Company"&gt;Firma&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="Male" selected="selected"&gt;Männlich&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="Female"&gt;Weiblich&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;/select&gt;
```

Comment: Has the below answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 9):

After some research here [dropdownlistfor does not select correct value in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381635/dropdownlistfor-does-not-select-correct-value-in-a-loop) I found a solution.

This works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId,
  new SelectList(Model.RentableGarageItems, "Value", "Text", Model.Renter.RentLines[0].GarageId))
```

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You missing the **Selected** property in the SelectedListItem creation. i.e Selected = (garage.Id == 2)

```
        var entities = new List<Guarage>()
        {
            new Guarage() {No = 1, Id = 1},
            new Guarage() {No = 2, Id = 2},
            new Guarage() {No = 3, Id = 3}
        };

        foreach (var garage in entities)
        {
            var s = new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = garage.No.ToString(),
                Value = garage.Id.ToString(),
                Selected = (garage.Id == 2)
            };
            RentableGarageItems.Add(s);
        }
```

This would have the 2 selected in the dropdown by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's works but it must be able to it without setting the selected value in a List of SelectListItems for two reasons: 1. I want to use the same list for more than on DropDownList with different preselected values. 2. It works perfect until I want to pre select from a property "deeper" in my model object. Please take a look at my updated post above. (Can't sent as comment, because it's to long). Here it works without setting the select value in the List of SelectListItems.

Answer (score 1):

Inlining Stephen Muecke's answer to [MVC5 Razor html.dropdownlistfor set selected when value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411482/1366033)

> Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop. This has been previously reported as an issue on CodePlex (not sure if its a bug or just a limitation)
>
> The are 2 options to solve this to ensure the correct option is selected based on the model property
>
> ---
>
> #### **Option 1**  - Use an `EditorTemplate`
>
> Create a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type in the collection. Create a partial in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AggregationLevelConfiguration.cshtml` (note the name must match the name of the type
>
> ```cs
> @model yourAssembly.AggregationLevelConfiguration
> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HelperCodeType, (SelectList)ViewData["CodeTypeItems"])
> .... // other properties of AggregationLevelConfiguration
> ```
>
> and then in the main view, pass the `SelectList` to the `EditorTemplate` as `additionalViewData`
>
> ```cs
> @using (Html.BeginForm())
> {
>   ...
>   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Configurations , new { CodeTypeItems = Model.CodeTypeItems })
>   ...
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### **Option 2** - Generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration and set the `selectedValue`
>
> In this option your property `CodeTypeItems` should to be `IEnumerable<GenericIdNameType>`, not a `SelectList` (or just make `codeTypes` a public property). Then in the main view
>
> ```cs
> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new SelectList(Model.CodeTypeItems, "Id", "Name", Model.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType)
> ```
>
> **Side note**: there is no need to use `new { id = "Configurations[0].HelperCodeType"` - the `DropDownListFor()` method already generated that `id` attribute

Note: Also double check that you don't have other non-list related binding issues as described in these questions:

- [Html.DropdownListFor selected value not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19476530/1366033)
- [DropDownListFor Not Selecting Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2278056/1366033)