# MVC5 Razor html.dropdownlistfor set selected when value is in array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have this `View`:

```
@model MyProject.Web.API.Models.AggregationLevelConfViewModel

[...]

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, (SelectList)Model.HelperCodeTypeItems, new { id = "Configurations[0].HelperCodeType" })
```

The `ViewModel` is:

```
public class AggregationLevelConfViewModel
{
    private readonly List<GenericIdNameType> codeTypes;
    private readonly List<GenericIdNameType> helperCodeTypes;

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CodeTypeItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(codeTypes, "Id", "Name"); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HelperCodeTypeItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(helperCodeTypes, "Id", "Name"); }
    }

    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }

    public string ProductionOrderName { get; set; }

    public IList<Models.AggregationLevelConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }

    public AggregationLevelConfViewModel()
    {
        // Load CodeTypes to show it as a DropDownList
        byte[] values = (byte[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(CodeTypes));

        codeTypes = new List<GenericIdNameType>();
        helperCodeTypes = new List<GenericIdNameType>();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            GenericIdNameType cType = new GenericIdNameType()
            {
                Id = values[i].ToString(),
                Name = EnumHelper.GetDescription((CodeTypes)values[i])
            };

            if (((CodeTypes)values[i]) != CodeTypes.NotUsed)
                codeTypes.Add(cType);

            helperCodeTypes.Add(cType);
        }
    }
}
```

And `Models.AggregationLevelConfiguration` is:

```
public class AggregationLevelConfiguration
{
    public byte AggregationLevelConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte CodeType { get; set; }
    public byte HelperCodeType { get; set; }
    public int PkgRatio { get; set; }
    public int RemainingCodes { get; set; }
}
```

I need to set selected value in these properties:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CodeTypeItems
{
    get { return new SelectList(codeTypes, "Id", "Name"); }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HelperCodeTypeItems
{
    get { return new SelectList(helperCodeTypes, "Id", "Name"); }
}
```

But I can't set it in `new SelectList(codeTypes, "Id", "Name");` or `new SelectList(helperCodeTypes, "Id", "Name");` because the selected value are in `Configurations` array: fields `AggregationLevelConfiguration.CodeType` and `AggregationLevelConfiguration.HelperCodeType`.

I think I have to set selected value in the View, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I set the selected values?

Comment: Its an unfortunate limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop. You need to generate a new `MutliSelectList` in each iteration (setting the `selectedValues` property in the constructor), or (better), use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `AggregationLevelConfiguration` and pass the `SelectList` to the template as `AdditionalViewData`

Comment: Thanks. I have understood that I have to use things but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer I gave about 6 months ago with the code for both options but not having any luck. If I cannot find it, I'll add an answer in an hour or so - but the following should work - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new SelectList(Model.HelperCodeTypeItems, "Value", "Text", Model.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new { ... })`

Comment: I'm working on a solution using jQuery to select the option.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks.

Comment: Its not really necessary to create a `SelectList` in the controller using that option - delete your `CodeTypeItems` and `HelperCodeTypeItems` and make the `codeTypes` and `helperCodeTypes` public properties, then it would be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new SelectList(Model.codeTypes, "Id", "Name", Model.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new { ... })`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately `@Html.DropDownListFor()` behaves a little differently than other helpers when rendering controls in a loop. This has been previously reported as an issue on CodePlex (not sure if its a bug or just a limitation)

The are 2 option to solve this to ensure the correct option is selected based on the model property

**Option 1** (using an `EditorTemplate`)

Create a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type in the collection. Create a partial in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AggregationLevelConfiguration.cshtml` (note the name must match the name of the type

```
@model yourAssembly.AggregationLevelConfiguration
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HelperCodeType, (SelectList)ViewData["CodeTypeItems"])
.... // other properties of AggregationLevelConfiguration
```

and then in the main view, pass the `SelectList` to the `EditorTemplate` as `additionalViewData`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ...
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Configurations , new { CodeTypeItems = Model.CodeTypeItems })
  ...
```

**Option 2** (generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration and set the `selectedValue`)

In this option your property `CodeTypeItems` should to be `IEnumerable<GenericIdNameType>`, not a `SelectList` (or just make `codeTypes` a public property). Then in the main view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType, new SelectList(Model.CodeTypeItems, "Id", "Name", Model.Configurations[0].HelperCodeType)
```

Side note: there is no need to use `new { id = "Configurations[0].HelperCodeType"` - the `DropDownListFor()` method already generated that `id` attribute

Comment: With option 2  you saved my day! Before, I used a hacky JavaScript loop to iterate through all my DropDownLists and set the selected value manually from hidden fields.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll just say it: MVC sucks.  I'm glad we have other options now!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this class to overcome an issue I was having with selecting an option in an html select list. I hope it helps someone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace Login_page.Models
{
    public class HTMLSelect
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> @class { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Boolean required { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectOption> SelectOptions { get; set; }

        public HTMLSelect(IEnumerable<SelectOption> options)
        {

        }

        public HTMLSelect(string id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public HTMLSelect(string id, string name, bool required, IEnumerable<SelectOption> options)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.required = required;
        }

        private string BuildOpeningTag()
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            text.Append("<select");
            text.Append(this.id != null ? " id=" + '"' + this.id + '"' : "");
            text.Append(this.name != null ? " name=" + '"' + this.name + '"' : "");
            text.Append(">");
            return text.ToString();

        }

        public string GenerateSelect(IEnumerable<SelectOption> options)
        {
            StringBuilder selectElement = new StringBuilder();
            selectElement.Append(this.BuildOpeningTag());
            foreach (SelectOption option in options)
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                text.Append("\t");
                text.Append("<option value=" + '"' + option.Value + '"');
                text.Append(option.Selected != false ? " selected=" + '"' + "selected" + '"' + ">" : ">");
                text.Append(option.Text);
                text.Append("</option>");
                selectElement.Append(text.ToString());
            }
            selectElement.Append("</select");
            return selectElement.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class SelectOption
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Boolean Selected { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And

```
public IEnumerable<SelectOption> getOrderTypes()
{
    List<SelectOption> orderTypes = new List<SelectOption>();
                        if (this.orderType == "OptionText")
                        {
                            orderTypes.Add(new SelectOption() { Value = "1", Text = "OptionText", Selected = true });
                        } else
                        {
                            orderTypes.Add(new SelectOption() { Value = "2", Text = "OptionText2" });
                        }
}
```

And to use it:

```
@{
    Login_page.Models.HTMLSelect selectElement = new Login_page.Models.HTMLSelect("order-types", "order-types");

}
@Html.Raw(selectElement.GenerateSelect(Model.getOrderTypes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave this in case it helps someone else. I had a very similar problem and none of the answers helped.

We had in a view this line at the top:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> exitFromTrustDeed = (ViewData["ExitFromTrustDeed"] as IEnumerable<string>).Select(e => new SelectListItem() { 
    Value = e, 
    Text = e,
    Selected = Model.ExitFromTrustDeed == e
});
```

and then below in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExitFromTrustDeed, exitFromTrustDeed, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**We had a property in my ViewData with the same name as the selector** for the lambda expression and for some reason that makes the dropdown to be rendered without any option selected.

We changed the name in ViewData to `ViewData["ExitFromTrustDeed2"]` and that made it work as expected.

Weird though.