# how to bring static values for a dynamically created row in a table in mvc view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table template and table as below in MVC view

**Template for dynamic row**

```
<table id="Newrelation" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="relation-%" style="width:100px" class="relation_type" name="survey_detail[#].relation" value></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="agegroup-%" style="width:100px" class="age_group" name="survey_detail[#].age_group" value></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="nodependent-%" style="width:100px" class="no_dependent" name="survey_detail[#].no_dependent" value></select>
            <input type="hidden" id="new_relation" name="survey_detail.Index" value="%" />
        </td>
        <td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Actual table**

```
<table id="relation" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px">
                Relation
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                Age Group
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                No: Dependent
            </th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.survey_detail.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.survey_detail[i].relation, (SelectList)@ViewBag.Relation,"--", new { @class = "m-wrap" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.survey_detail[i].age_group, (SelectList)@ViewBag.Agegroup,"--", new { @class = "m-wrap" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.survey_detail[i].no_dependent, (SelectList)@ViewBag.Number, "--", new { @class = "m-wrap" })
                        <input type="hidden" name="survey_detail.Index" value="@i" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
<table>
```

**Jquery to attach new row on button click**

```
$('#add_rel').click(function (e) {
    var body = $('#relation').children('tbody').first();
    var index = (new Date()).getTime();
    var clone = $('#Newrelation').clone();
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"relation-%"/g, 'relation-' + index));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"agegroup-%"/g, 'agegroup-' + index));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"nodependent-%"/g, 'nodependent-' + index));
    var newrow1 = clone.find('tr');
    body.append(newrow1);
});
```

And it attach new row to the table but all the select list comes blank eventhough the `@ViewBag.Relation,@ViewBag.agegroup,@ViewBag.Number` has data.

Please guide me to get values on the select list

Comment: The `<select>` elements in the template that your cloning do not have any `<option>` elements so there is nothing to display. You will need to generate and append the options elements to the new row based on values in the `ViewBag` properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can i give option property in template with the viewbag?

Comment: As a side note, your use of `DropDownListFor()` inside a loop will not work correctly - the first option will always be selected when the page is initially displayed

Comment: @StephenMuecke can u pls show one eg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your use of `DropDownListFor()` will not work correctly (the first option will always be selected no mater what the value of the property is) as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array/37411482#37411482) (note in your case you will not be able to use the `EditorTemplate` option).

To solve this and the main issue in your question, change your `ViewBag` properties from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is an object containing just 2 properties, for example

```cs
public class OptionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then the code in the GET method would be something like

```
ViewBag.Relation = db.Relations.Select(x => new OptionVM
{
    ID = x.RelationId,
    Name = x.SomeOtherPropertyToDisplay
});
```

In the view, for the generating the existing items, use

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.survey_detail.Count; i++)
{
    ....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.survey_detail[i].relation, 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.Relation, "ID", "Name", Modelsurvey_detail[i].relation), 
        "--", 
        new { @class = "m-wrap" })
    ....
}
```

which will ensure the correct options is selected.

Now you can use those same `ViewBag` properties to add the `<option>` elements to your template when the page is first loaded.

```js
// Get the first select element in the template
var relationSelect = $('#Newrelation').find('select').eq(0);
// Create a javascript array of the options
var relationOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Relations));
// Create and append option elements
relationSelect.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--'));
$.each(relationOptions, function(index, item) {
    relationSelect.append($('<option></option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Name));
});
```

and repeat for the 2nd and 3rd `<select>` elements in the template.

Side notes:

1. It is not necessary to add `id` attributes to the `<select>` and
   `<input type="hidden">` elements in the template and you should not
   be adding one to the `<input type="button">` because that is
   generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes).
2. Your creating a `null` ("--") option which suggest you will be
   validating that a selection has been made, in which case you should
   also be adding `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property (and
   adding the html that it generates to your template (refer [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)
   for more detail). If that is the case, you will also need to reparse
   the validator each time a new item is added (as shown in the
   previous link).
3. Finally, I recommend you use a view model containing properties for
   the collections used to generate the options rather than using
   `ViewBag`.

Comment: `var relationOptions = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Relation)';` giving error `Unterminated string literal.  Strings that start with a quotation mark (") must be terminated before the end of the line.  However, strings that start with @ and a quotation mark (@") can span multiple lines`

Comment: Oops - just noticed I was missing a closing `)` - should be `var relationOptions = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Relation))';` - see edit - but let me check there are no other typos by creating the fiddle.

Comment: Found another as well (there should be no quotes). See [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kHN3en) for a working example (note I'll delete the fiddle in a few hours so fork it if you want to keep it)

Comment: thanks for your help..but still the select list is getting empty..the fiddle also when i run the select list don't have any value

Comment: The fiddle works fine so not sure what your saying - the html is just `<select></select>` and has no options - and its the script which is adding the 4 options to it.

Comment: for me when the fiddle runs the selectlist is blank :(

Comment: What? Close it and click on the link again (sometimes it can be a bit slow and you can get a timeout exception)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113583/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).