# MVC @Html.Dropdownlistfor Not Returning the Correct Values From List

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this Dropdownlist in my view that reads from my database and it currently reads the correct thing but it only reads each character. For instance, If I have "ATL" as a location in my location table, I will get a dropdownlist of 3 items "A","T","L" instead of just the one item "ATL".

I've tried just using just regular `@Html.DropDownList` and got the DDL looking alright but I kept getting `"System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Location.VYFY456886V..."` along with "ATL" in my DDL and ended up with 2 items even though 1 item is in my table and I could never find out how to get rid of the weird `"System.Data"` thing.

So i figured using `DropDownListFor()` would be better for my database since it doesn't give me the `"System"` thing in my DDL.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult TakeInventory()
{
    CTS_InventoryEntities entities = new CTS_InventoryEntities();
    return View(from Asset in entities.Assets select Asset)     
}
```

I have a table called "Asset" and a table called "Location". The Asset table has a FK from the Location table (LocationKey).

Here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CTS_Inventory.Models.Asset>    
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Item: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.AssetKey, new { @placeholder = "Enter Asset Tag", @Value = "" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Inventory Owner: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.InventoryOwner)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Location: </label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Location, new SelectList (item.Location.LocationName))
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm just trying to get the LocationName to be selected from the DDL without it breaking it up into separate characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck on this for quite a while. Thank you

EDIT:

My AssetViewModel:

```
public partial class Asset
    {
        public int AssetKey { get; set; }
        public int ProductKey { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerKey { get; set; }
        public int ModelKey { get; set; }
        public int LocationKey { get; set; }
        public int ClientSiteKey { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public string InventoryOwner { get; set; }
        public string InventoriedBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime InventoryDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

        public virtual ClientSite ClientSite { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

My LocationViewModel:

```
 public partial class Location
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Location()
        {
            this.Assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
        }

        public int LocationKey { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable <SelectListItem> LocationName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewInventory()
        {
            CTS_InventoryEntities entities = new CTS_InventoryEntities();
            ViewBag.LocationKey = new SelectList(entities.Locations, "LocationKey", "LocationName");
            ViewBag.ClientSiteKey = new SelectList(entities.ClientSites, "ClientSiteKey", "ClientSiteName");
            return View();
```

LocationViewModel:

```
public partial class LocationViewModel
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public LocationViewModel()
        {
            this.Assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
        }
        public int LocationKey { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public int LocationList { get; set; }
        public int ClientSiteKey { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATE 2:

Added this to my LocationViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationList { get; set; }
public string LocationSelected { get; set; }
```

Added this to my controller:

```
CTS_InventoryEntities entities = new CTS_InventoryEntities();
            LocationViewModel model = new LocationViewModel()

            {
                LocationList = new SelectList(entities.Locations,"LocationKey","LocationName")
            };
```

Added this to my View:

```
<label>Location: </label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LocationSelected,Model.LocationList)
```

Comment: Firstly you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)). Second you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object which is what `Location` is. And `LocationName` is obviously a string (which is `IEnumerable` and why its generating an option for each character in the array). In short - nothing your doing makes sense. You need a property to bind to, and you need a property which is a collection to generate the options.

Comment: So, take out the "from" statement in my return? And yes I know LocationName is a string but it worked when i had DropDownList(). The other item "System" item always showed up in the DDL when I did that. And use a for loop instead of a foreach loop? Based on the answer in the other post you provided. Also my TextBoxfor() functions seem to work correctly. Or do I need a for loop for those also?

Comment: In order to generate a `<select>` using `DropDownListFor()` you need 2 things - a property to bind to (which needs to be `string` of a value type (e.g. `int`) and you need a collection - in you case a collection of `Location` (from your location table). Suggest you read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to get you started with the basics,

Comment: and then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array/37411482#37411482) to understand what your need to do when using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop

Comment: Finally got it to work. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as one. I needed to make my Locations as a collection like you suggested. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: I cant until you at least show your models for both tables.

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought i had it correct but I don't. But  I changed my model for location to `public int LocationKey { get; set; }
public IEnumerable <SelectListItem> LocationName { get; set; }`

Comment: Edit your question to show your models (for both `Asset` and `Location` tables)

Comment: My controller is where I'm having the most problems. The page that the code is loading on reads from multiple tables in my db, so I can't just specify that I want to `return View('Location')`.  I have to return other items also. My controller is `Location model = new Location() {
                LocationName = new SelectList(CTS_InventoryEntities.Locations, "ID", "Name");
                }` I've tried looking at the links you posted but I cant figure out what should I use to for my `new <SelectList>(???, "ID","Name"`. I dont have a db.<tablename> to connect my db.

Comment: Your field in the database `Location` table cannot be `List<SelectListItem> LocationName` (that would never even compile!) - it needs to be `string LocationName`

Comment: I changed it back. My view is all wrong now. I cant figure out how to return the view from my asset table and my location table from my view because I'm using both of them. I can only return one view at a time, which can only be asset or location, not both which is really throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Read all the links I gave you carefully - you use a view model with a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LocationList` and you have property (say) `int SelectedLocation` to bind to (plus only the other properties of `Asset` that you need in the view) and then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.SelectedLocation, Model.LocationList)`

Comment: `public ActionResult TakeInventory()
        {
        
            Location model = new Location() {
                
                LocationName = new SelectList(CTS_InventoryEntities.Locations, "ID", "Name")
                }
return View(model);` This is what my controller looks like now. The "CTS_InventoryEntities.Locations" is wrong and I don't know why?

Comment: Okay, I'll read it over again. I will update you whenever I can get it remotely working correctly.

Comment: I think I have it working now good enough. You definitely steered me in the right direction. I was able to get back the DDL with me database entries. I will update my question with my current viewModel and controller. I'm sure it needs some more work but I'm able to get a DDL with my items in it so I'm happy with that after countless hours of reading and learning.

Comment: Your still way off track, and you sill have not read [Will there be any conflict if i specify the viewBag name to be equal to the model property name inside @Html.DropDownListFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/will-there-be-any-conflict-if-i-specify-the-viewbag-name-to-be-equal-to-the-mode/37162557#37162557)

Comment: I think I figured it out correctly like you were stating. I'm not using ViewBag anymore because I see it can cause some issues. But I'm using your advice and added those things into my project and now I am getting my data displayed in the DDL no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please Do one thing .

First create List of SelectLsitItem from database and fill lt .

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetCity(ref string StateCode, string ZipCode)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lstCity = new List<SelectListItem>();
            try
            {

                SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@StateCode", StateCode), new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", ZipCode) };
                DataSet dsCity = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetCityByStateCodeZipCode", parameters);

                if (dsCity != null && dsCity.Tables.Count > 0 && dsCity.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    lstCity = (from drCity in dsCity.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                                  select new SelectListItem { Text = drCity["City"].ToString(), Value = drCity["City"].ToString() }).ToList();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StateCode))
                    {
                        StateCode = dsCity.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StateCode"].ToString();
                    }

                }
                return lstCity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return lstCity;
            }
        }
```

After Stored SelectLsitItem  into viewbag .

```
ViewBag.GLDeductible=GetCity("A","B");
```

After assign that viewbag to dropdownlist .

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.otherLimitsMappingModel.DamageToPremises, ViewBag.GLDeductible as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>})
```

It will be work for you.

If you will stuck in my code then tell me i will help you .

Thanks.

Comment: then Please   give me upvote and mark as right answer .