# Extension method not working as it should

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a app which is being developed using C# and Asp.Net MVC.

On one of the views I have around 10 `DropDowns` which users must select. The selected value is stored into the database.

For Example:

1. `DropDown` has `Value` of `1` and `Text` appears as `First Main Fault`
2. `DropDown` has `Value` of  `One` and `Text` appears as `First Sub Fault`

Now users can come back and edit their records. So I want to show them the `DropDown` which is already selected with the value of what's stored in the database.

For this I make use of the following extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> textSelector, Func<T, string> valueSelector, Func<T, bool> selecter)
{
   return items.OrderBy(item => textSelector(item))
      .Select(item =>
       new SelectListItem
       {
          Selected = selecter(item),
          Text = textSelector(item),
          Value = valueSelector(item)
        });
}
```

Which I call as

```
var mainFaultSelectedDdl = mainFaults.ToSelectListItems(
            m => m.MainFaultDescription,
            m => m.Id.ToString(),
            m => m.Id == mainFaultId); //mainFaultId here equals to 1. I've also tried m.Id.ToString() == mainFaultId.ToString() but still the same issue

var subFaultSelectedDdl = subFaults.ToSelectListItems(
            s => s.SubFaultDescription,
            s => s.SubFaultDescription,
            s => s.SubFaultDescription == erst.SubFault); //erst.SubFault here equals to One
```

When I debug my code I can see both of the above `DropDowns` `Selected` is set to `True` but in the view The MainFault `DropDown` doesn't be selected but the SubFault `DropDown` is selected.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

This is how I'm currently generating the `DropDown` in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Serial.MainFault, Model.MainFaultDdl, "Please select a main fault", new { id = "mainFaults", @class = "form-control main-ddl" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Serial.SubFault, Model.SubFaultDdl, "Please select a sub fault", new { id = "subFaults", @class = "form-control main-ddl" })
```

Comment: How are you generating your dropdownlists in the view. Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when you bind to a model

Comment: where do you set the value for `mainFaultId` and `erst.SubFault`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated my question to include the code from the view. It works for one and not the other that's what's confusing me

Comment: @HimBromBeere `mainFaultId` is set just before I call my extension method and same with `erst.SubFault`

Comment: You binding to the `MainFault` and `SubFault` properties, and its their value which determines the option that is selected (internally the `DropDownListFor()` method builds its own `SelectList` so your code that sets the `Selected` property is pointless)

Comment: @StephenMuecke What would be the most appropriate way to go about this then?

Comment: If the value of `Serial.MainFault` is (say) `1` and your have an option that has `value="1"` then that option will be selected. You just need to set the value of `MainFault` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: And there is already a built in method for generating a `SelectList` - using `new SelectList(mainFaults, "Id", "MainFaultDescription")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke So i've been over complicating it for no reason :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130689/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding works by binding to the value of your property, in your case the value of `Serial.MainFault`. If the value of `Serial.MainFault` matches one of option values (defined by the value of the `Id` property of the objects in `mainFaults`) then it will be selected. If it does not match a value, then the first option will be selected because something has to be.

Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when using the `DropDownListFor()`  method because internally the method builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to (note that there is an exception to this -  in the case of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array/37411482#37411482)).

However, your extension methods do not seem necessary since MVC already has a method for building an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` using one of the [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) constructors.

Based on the code you have shown, your GET method can simply be

```
var model = new YourModel();
model.Serial.MainFault = mainFaultId; // set the value to be displayed initially
model.MainFaultDdl = new SelectList(mainFaults, "Id", "MainFaultDescription"); // generate the options
return View(model);
```

or alternatively you can use the following to generate the options

```
model.MainFaultDdl = mainFaults.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = x.MainFaultDescription
};
```

and the correct option will be displayed in the view.

Comment: Thank you for this.