# How to set a default value for multiple elements using DropDownListFor on a POST view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with an enumerable property that will be set with multiple dropdown controls on a page.

My ViewModel has a collection `AvailableItems` for the possible options, `SelectedItems` for the return values, and `PreSelectedItems` for the default values.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        AvailableItems = new[]
        {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "unselected"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value2"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key3", "value3"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key4", "value4"),
            };
    }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AvailableItems { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public string[] PreSelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller has two actions, one is a `GET` and the other a `POST`. They set two different sets of `PreSelectedItems`.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            PreSelectedItems = new[] { null, "key4", null }
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var oldViewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            PreSelectedItems = new[] { "key3", null, null },
            SelectedItems = new[] { null, null, "key1" }
        };

        return View(oldViewModel);
    }
```

Finally, the View displays the dropdownlists (the number of which will vary based on other parameters).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItems,
            new SelectList(
                Model.AvailableItems,
                "Key",
                "Value",
                Model.PreSelectedItems[i]))
    </p>
}
```

The `GET` action works absolutely fine, with the middle dropdown showing 'value4'.

The `POST` action's viewModel parameter is populated correctly, but the resulting View displays the dropdowns with no preset/default values. It doesn't matter if the original ViewModel or a newly created one are returned (as long as `PreSelectedItems` is populated), no default values are set.

I have no idea why it works on a `GET` but not a `POST` for an identical ViewModel.

Comment: you mean when you send data to HttpPost and return model old selected items are not changed?

Comment: That's right, even with the correct properties set on the ViewModel (and confirmed when debugging) the View doesn't set the default values on Post the same as it does on a Get

Comment: Despite what you may think, your GET is not really binding correctly either (because a `<select>` what is not `multiple` cannot bind to `IEnumerable<string>` and so it falls back to you hack of using `PreSelectedItems` (and you will never get any validation with this). The only way to make this work without using further hacks in the POST metod is bind to a collection of of model containing property `string SelectedItem` and pass 3 objects to the view (where the values of `SelectedItem` are set in the GET method)

Comment: And for a bit more info on binding dropwdownlists in a loop, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array/37411482#37411482)

Comment: I know the GET is not binding to display from that property, but when posted, SelectedItems contains an array of each of the different dropdown lists selections. (the original ViewModel code should be `string[] SelectedItems`, not `IEnumerable`).

Comment: `string[]` is `IEnumerable<string>`! But its clear your not getting this at all.

Comment: No, I'm not, sorry about that. This code, and this answer, do what I need it to do. Not sure I've explained myself properly though.

Comment: Writing a bad hack in the POST method to solve bad code in the GET method is not the way to write code :)

Comment: Could you post an answer showing a better way to do this then please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when ever you change the `Model` or any value in `Model` after a request you have to `clear ModelState` because when you return to the view it checks `ModelSate` before `Model` so you should do something like this

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
            var oldViewModel = new ViewModel
            {
                PreSelectedItems = new[] { "key3", null, null }
            }

            ModelState.Clear();  
            return View(oldViewModel);
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't make any change to the observed behaviour.

Comment: remove SelectedItems  and then check