# DropDownListFor is not selecting existing value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist for

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => f.MovieID, (SelectList)ViewBag.MoviesList, "--Select One--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In the controller I set the ViewBag.MovesList to  a SelectList. It is a valid Select List. I'm trying to reuse the same select list for multiple items in a foreach loop. However, when it is rendered the existing MovieID value is not being selected in the drop down list. I have seen many similar questions but none of their root causes I am seeing in mine. Also, based on other questions simimar, this is slightly different then others because it is inside of a loop.

Comment: shouldn't that be model => model.MovieID or f => f.MovieID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC5 Razor html.dropdownlistfor set selected when value is in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MovieID, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.MoviesList, "Value", "Text", Model.MovieID), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Where **Value** is what you want to pass to the action invoked and **Text** is what you want to show in the dropdown.

Comment: I'm going to tweak this answer slightly but I believe this should do it. Just sad I need to create a new SelectList everytime. I can't just set a property on it and change the selected value for each drop down list in a loop